# Bash - recursively search files from the list and copy them to destination

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of file names (without full path, only file names containing extensions) which I would like to find in subfolders of specified path (*dir*) and copy them to destination (*dest*) folder.
Each file name is separated by the newline character.

I'm not aware of any tool to do that (i.e. I can't find appropriate option in Gnome Commander), so I wrote a small Bash script for that:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="~/Dropbox/in_THIS_folder_and_subfolders_of_this_folder_I_have_files_which_I_wish_to_copy"
dest="~/PleaseCopyMeHere"
listOfFileNamesToCopy="ext-SM_OPER_MIR_CLF33A_20160303T000000_20160305T235959_300_002_7_1.DBL.nc.png
ext-SM_OPER_MIR_CLF33A_20160306T000000_20160308T235959_300_003_7_1.DBL.nc.png
DA_TC_MIR_CL_33SMOS_20160305.DBL.nc_hist_pl.pdf
msk_TC_cal_sub_msk_TC_ca__sum__SMOS_20160303.DBL_div_filt.tif.png
summsk_TC_cal_sub_msk_TC_ca__sum__SMOS_20160303.DBL_div_filt.tif_hist_pl.pdf
"

while read line; do
   find "$dir" -name "$line" -exec cp '{}' $dest    
done < "$listOfFileNamesToCopy"
```

Unfortunately it's not working and I have no idea what is wrong. Could you suggest solution, please?

Comment: Are the files in variable `listOfFileNamesToCopy` new line separated?

Comment: Yes, they're. If this is source of an issue, maybe I should separate them by different character or save list of files in file?

Comment: Note that the tilde expansion in your assignments of `dir` and `dest` will not occur, since they are quoted. Move the tildes out of the quotes, or use the variable `$HOME` instead of the tilde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is right, but the input to the loop is provided in an incorrect way. The syntax you adopted is for reading contents of a file. But to expand a variable use a here-string syntax(`<<<"$variable"`) which expands the variable and sends it as the input to the loop.

Since the values in variables are separated by `\n` entries, you need to de-limit by that character while setting input field separator, `IFS` while running the loop i.e. (or) using the de-limiter flag provided by `read` command with `-d$'\n'`
which is by default the operation of `read`. Also remove he `~` in double-quotes and use `$HOME` for expansion as @gniourf_gniourf suggested in the comments.

```
dir="$HOME/Dropbox/in_THIS_folder_and_subfolders_of_this_folder_I_have_files_which_I_wish_to_copy"
dest="$HOME/PleaseCopyMeHere"

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line
do
    find "$dir" -name "$line" -exec cp '{}' "$dest" \;
done <<<"$listOfFileNamesToCopy"
```

should solve your problem.

As a side note, when unsure of the new-line separation in variable values, use `hexdump -c` to see it for yourself. In your case, I did, hex byte level representation of the data enabled by the `-c` flag and see the `\n` characters after each file-name.

```
dudeOnMac:myScripts $ echo "$listOfFileNamesToCopy" | hexdump -c
0000000   e   x   t   -   S   M   _   O   P   E   R   _   M   I   R   _
0000010   C   L   F   3   3   A   _   2   0   1   6   0   3   0   3   T
0000020   0   0   0   0   0   0   _   2   0   1   6   0   3   0   5   T
0000030   2   3   5   9   5   9   _   3   0   0   _   0   0   2   _   7
0000040   _   1   .   D   B   L   .   n   c   .   p   n   g  \n   e   x
0000050   t   -   S   M   _   O   P   E   R   _   M   I   R   _   C   L
0000060   F   3   3   A   _   2   0   1   6   0   3   0   6   T   0   0
0000070   0   0   0   0   _   2   0   1   6   0   3   0   8   T   2   3
0000080   5   9   5   9   _   3   0   0   _   0   0   3   _   7   _   1
0000090   .   D   B   L   .   n   c   .   p   n   g  \n   D   A   _   T
00000a0   C   _   M   I   R   _   C   L   _   3   3   S   M   O   S   _
00000b0   2   0   1   6   0   3   0   5   .   D   B   L   .   n   c   _
00000c0   h   i   s   t   _   p   l   .   p   d   f  \n   m   s   k   _
00000d0   T   C   _   c   a   l   _   s   u   b   _   m   s   k   _   T
00000e0   C   _   c   a   _   _   s   u   m   _   _   S   M   O   S   _
00000f0   2   0   1   6   0   3   0   3   .   D   B   L   _   d   i   v
0000100   _   f   i   l   t   .   t   i   f   .   p   n   g  \n   s   u
0000110   m   m   s   k   _   T   C   _   c   a   l   _   s   u   b   _
0000120   m   s   k   _   T   C   _   c   a   _   _   s   u   m   _   _
0000130   S   M   O   S   _   2   0   1   6   0   3   0   3   .   D   B
0000140   L   _   d   i   v   _   f   i   l   t   .   t   i   f   _   h
0000150   i   s   t   _   p   l   .   p   d   f  \n  \n                
000015c
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need `IFS=$'\n'`. Are you confusing `IFS` with the delimiter provided by `-d`? By default, `read` reads lines (so the default is similar to `-d $'\n'`). `IFS` is used for another purpose (which looks irrelevant in your case). Also, a good advice to give is to use an array instead of a newline-separated string. So that the whole `while`/`read` thing becomes useless altogether. And by the way, `dir` and `dest` need to be quoted.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Is there a down-side of using my approach, BTW I tested it before posting it as my own.

Comment: No down-side, just that `IFS=$'\n'` is useless. But you should definitely use arrays!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Agree the point about arrays! but OP wanted to process each file on the variable, are you suggesting store them into array and use `find`?

Comment: Yes, store them in a array, and loop through the array (instead of looping through the lines of the string).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Point learned for the day! Will use that logic in the future.

Comment: No idea why, but when I save mentioned script as a file, add execute permissions (chmod +x) and tries to execute it by typing:

sh scriptname.sh --> I receive: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

./scriptname.sh  --> It works properly

Comment: @matandked: You are running the script by the `POSIX` shell `sh` in which some the standard features are not present, Run it as `bash scriptname.sh`

Comment: @matandked: or more efficiently add `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of script to tell the shell run it as a `bash` shell

Comment: @matandked: Appreciate you found it useful!